# Laravel tinker not working with error "resource is not a valid stream resource"

Tags: php, laravel, orm, query-builder, tinker

I'm working with Laravel tinker, but if I run some query builder, such as  `\Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::table('users')->get();`, I always get the following error messages without expected result:

```
TypeError  fwrite(): supplied resource is not a valid stream resource.
```

Even when I run simple commands in tinker like `echo 2 + 3;`, I still have the error message:

```
> echo 2 + 3;
5
   TypeError  fwrite(): supplied resource is not a valid stream resource.
```

What can be the cause for this?

Comment: check you code (anything but vendor folder) for the fwrite() method call (maybe in config files). if you didnt find the culprit, i suggest you delete the vendor folder and run `composer install`

Comment: I found the reason in this anwser: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73940400/usr-bin-less-unrecognized-option-x-laravel-docker-error
The reason is that in the docker container where laravel runs, there's no `less` package installed somehow. So I just ran `apk add less` and then it works.